# JQ - Filtering JSON file by using Startswith and making the search case insensitive

Tags: json, jq

Below is an example of the JSON file I am trying to run:

```
{
    "$itemsPerPage": 1208,
    "$resources": [
        {
            "$uuid": "7b44f5b6-a5bd-4c7a-8d4a-581ff36a1072",
            "$etag": "2016-08-12T12:29:33Z",
            "BPSNAM": "InfoCenter",
            "BPSNUM": "AO011",
            "BPSNUM_REF": {
                "$title": "InfoCenter",
                "$description": "InfoCenter"
            },
            "CUR": "AOA",
            "CUR_REF": {
                "$title": "Kwanza",
                "$description": "Angolan kwanza",
                "$symbol": "",
                "$scale": 2,
                "$precision": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "$uuid": "25ee60e6-dd55-4c0a-842d-8e66234342b8",
            "$etag": "2015-01-23T09:18:55Z",
            "BPSNAM": "NeoPneus - Componentes e Pneus",
            "BPSNUM": "AO051",
            "BPSNUM_REF": {
                "$title": "NeoPneus",
                "$description": "NeoPneus - Componentes e Pneus"
            },
            "CUR": "AOA",
            "CUR_REF": {
                "$title": "Kwanza",
                "$description": "Angolan kwanza",
                "$symbol": "",
                "$scale": 2,
                "$precision": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "$uuid": "00682755-d9c7-4755-928a-439f09555e77",
            "$etag": "2014-02-04T18:49:06Z",
            "BPSNAM": "SuperBikes - Acessorios",
            "BPSNUM": "AO052",
            "BPSNUM_REF": {
                "$title": "SuperBikes",
                "$description": "SuperBikes - Acessorios"
            },
            "CUR": "AOA",
            "CUR_REF": {
                "$title": "Kwanza",
                "$description": "Angolan kwanza",
                "$symbol": "",
                "$scale": 2,
                "$precision": 11
            }
        }
```

I'm using the below which outputs the 3 results I want. However, this is a insensitive contains but I want to search by startswith:

```
.["$resources"]|.[]|(select(.BPSNAM | test("A";"i")))|.BPSNAM,.BPSNUM,.CUR
```

How do I search by startswith? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Question could be improved by correctly formatting the code sections and providing a bit more detail in terms of what the *desired* result would be compared to what the actual result is now.

Comment: Thanks John. The above JQ code gives me results that BPSNAM that CONTAIN "A". I want the results that startswith "A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter, 'startswith/0', but since you have gone to the trouble of using 'test/2' with the "i" option, let's stick with that:

```
test("^A"; "i")
```